# Pass data from nuxt module to plugin

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to pass data that I get from my module options down to a plugin. So let's say this is my module:

```
module.exports = function (moduleOptions) {
  const options = {
    ...this.options.moduleName,
    ...moduleOptions
  }


  this.addPlugin({
    src: resolve(__dirname, 'plugin.js'),
    options
  })
}
```

and this is my plugin

```
import { createStore } from 'lib';

export default async ({ store, app }) => {
  const settings = {
    axios: app.$axios,
    models: <% options.models %>
  }

  settings.axios = app.$axios;

  createStore(settings).install()(store)
};
```

and this is my config

```
const { resolve } = require('path')

module.exports = {
  rootDir: resolve(__dirname, '..'),
  buildDir: resolve(__dirname, '.nuxt'),
  srcDir: __dirname,
  render: {
    resourceHints: false
  },
  modules: [
    'moduleName'
  ],
  moduleName: {
    { models: require(resolve(__dirname, '../example/models')) }
  }
}
```

it throws

```
axios: app.$axios,
       7 |     models:
    >  8 |   }
```

where models is just empty, nothing behind it. No null, no undefined.

But if I do `<% console.log(options.models) %>` it will show the models that I've loaded. Btw models is just an array of classes.

These models must be configurable, so how do I pass these data from my `nuxt.config.js` via a module to my plugin?

Hope somebody knows :)

Answer (score 0):

I've worked around this issue using an require in my plugin instead of my config.